# 3D models of adult male brain in the Blender software? Any open-sourced version for research?

Tags: human-anatomy, brain, software, 3d-structure, visualization

I am trying to find 3D model of brains. I am particularly interested in adult-male -brains in Blender-model. I could find such 3D models of brains for sale [here](http://brain.turbosquid.com/3d-Models/3ds/max/xsi/c4d/obj) but because I am researching I would like to use some open-sourced candidate so anyone could preview things. So does there exist 3D models of brains in Blender?

Comment: I am interested in this as well

Comment: ...this movie under cc3 and some brain model: http://mango.blender.org/gallery/

Comment: A side note, for those interested in mouse brain anatomy: you may want to have a look at the Allen Brain Atlas website, particularly to [Brain Explorer](http://mouse.brain-map.org/static/brainexplorer)

Comment: <childishness>Am I the only one who initially (mis)read "adult male brain in a blender"? :)</childishness>

Answer (score 3):

There is a model of an adult, male, real human brain here:
http://brainder.org/download/brain-for-blender/

It can be imported into Blender or any other 3D application that can read Wavefront OBJ or Stanford PLY formats.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/max-human-brain/580672

That one is only 30 which *really isn't* bad for a model. You will have trouble finding an  anatomically correct model for free.

I am curious, is the male brain that much different from the female brain? And do you want just the brain or a whole head with the skeleton and other anatomical features? And if you would like to elaborate, I am curious about what end product you are looking for.

Side note: Autodesk has 'student' license version of software --in case you want to try learning Maya or 3Ds max, the latter has Retopology tools. 
You can download from here:
https://students.autodesk.com/?nd=download_center

ITKsnap is a program you could use to get 3d data from ct or mri scans 
http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.Downloads
MRI and CT data can be found here:
http://www.osirix-viewer.com/Downloads.html

I know you just wanted a free model, but the above are the steps to get to one at least.

Comment: Academia is mostly against the photo electricity of brains with mammals https://twitter.com/heoalov/status/274090762524848128 -- just curious: placebo or some other effect with led-tosslink-in-ear?

Comment: Err photosensitivity -- still requiring placebo test, easy trials: get cheap toslinks and different intensity light. Can you detect it? Does skin-senses become different after some use or just placebo? I cannot understand if not placebo, how does it work? If LEDs were UV, then D vitamin? Otherwise what is the physiological reaction? I do not know but pretty curious so investigating brains and ears etc

Answer (score 1):

I think all models are too generic out there. 
Radiological models you can find in [imaios.com](https://www.imaios.com/en)'s e-Anatomy where the Premium access gives you some RTG, CT and MRI videos which you can combine to form some 3D models. 
I am working with the visualization of CNS lymphatic vessels [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/41821/cns-lymphatic-vessels-around-ventricles-lat-et-4th) where I would like to create thin membranes to visualize how deep the lymphatic circulation goes.