# CNS lymphatic vessels around ventricles lat et 4th?

Tags: neurology, central-nervous-system, lymphatic-system

I am searching for precise locations of the lymphatic vessels of the CNS based on the applications of the article [here](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v523/n7560/full/nature14432.html).
However, I did not find any when having a focus on the immediate region around ventricles (lateral and fourth). 
I know this 2D visualization of the lymphatic vessels:

[image]

and this visualization at perivascular lobes

[image]

I am interested in how much the lymphatic vessels cover the lateral sides and ventricles.
I know this Blender application [here](http://brainder.org/publications/brain-for-blender/) where I consider *Full hemispheres, each as a single mesh* most useful. 
However, I have a problem in adding those small membranes on top of each hemispheres and there lymphatic vessels because I do not know how evenly I should put those in the model. 
I am particularly interested in the ventricles and how lymphatic vessels are around them.

How can you visualize the CNS lymphatic vessels around the immediate neighbourhood of ventricles (lateral and fourth) in 3D?